# JSON error while parsing lines of a file in an addon web accessible resources

Tags: json

Within the background part of an addon in firefox I have a JSON formatted file (newDicFile.txt) that includes 499 lines. Here is just a few lines of it.

```
{ "key" :"бить", "tWord" :"3", "conjug" :"4", "palat" :"0", "accent" :"1", "radical" :"бь", "radAcc" :"бь", "radicalP" :"би", "radPAcc" :"би́", "accentP" :"0", "translation" :"battre,  frapper", "counter" :"  побить ", "info" :""}
{ "key" :"бросить", "tWord" :"2", "conjug" :"2", "palat" :"1", "accent" :"0", "radical" :"броса", "radAcc" :"броса́", "radicalP" :"броси", "radPAcc" :"бро́си", "accentP" :"0", "translation" :"jeter", "counter" :"бросать  ","info" :""}
{ "key" :"броситься", "tWord" :"-", "conjug" :"-", "palat" :"-", "accent" :"-", "accentP" :"-", "radical" :"", " radAcc" :"", "radicalP" :"", "radPAcc" :"", "translation" :"se  jeter,  se  précipiter", "counter" :"бросаться  ", "info" :""}
```

In my code I try to make an array of javascript object of it:

```
self.buildDicArrayFromNewFile = function(){
    var dicArray=[];
    var dictionary=fileRead(browser.extension.getURL("web_accessible_resources/newDicFile.txt"),'UTF-8');
    var lines=dictionary.split("\n");
    //console.log(lines.toString());
    var i=0;
    console.log(lines.length);
    for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
        //console.log(lines[i]);
        dicArray.push(JSON.parse(lines[i]));
    }

    console.log("Creating dicArray finished! Ready to store it in indexedDB.");
    //console.log(dicArray.toString());
    //self.storeDictionary(dicArray);
};
```

When running the function from console I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

It seems that each line in lines is correct. I can check that deleting the comment hash at 5th line of the code.

Moreover, if I replace lines[i] with a fixed value e.g. line[0], or line[1] or line[2] I have 499 objects created by the JSON.parse with no errors which seems to indicate that each line is parsable by JSON.

To be comprehensive, the trouble is the same if I limit the size of the file to the 3 lines I have tested individually.

I don't really understand what is happening.

Comment: Made it out. I seems that the split instructions add a blank line at the end that causes the error. Adding a try catch prove to be very useful in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Made it out. I seems that the split instructions add a blank line at the end that causes the error. Adding a try catch prove to be very useful in such a case. –